# CodeIgniter losing session after awhile in AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a simple long polling situation.

jQuery

```
function poll(){
    $.get(url,{},function(data){ poll(); });
}
```

PHP *(timing stuff deleted for brevity)*

```
function responds_to_poll()
{
    if( ! $this->current_user()->is_logged_in())
    {
        redirect('auth/login');
    }

    echo json_encode("Whats up?");
}
```

I'll watch Firebug for 5-10 minutes and it works fine but eventually it will say `GET (302 Redirect)` and the response will contain the html in my `auth/login.php` file.

The sessions are database driven with native `CI_Session` class. They expire after 2 hours, not 5-10 minutes. I've tried a couple things seen in other questions but nothing has worked so far. What am I missing?

Comment: No, I rolled my own Authentication library. is_logged_in() simply returns TRUE or FALSE based on `($this->session->userdata('logged_in') === TRUE)`

Comment: This is a well-known bug with Codeigniter, something to do with the session cookie not being updated I think. I would recommend doing a search because there are many existing solutions.

Comment: This is a well-known bug with Codeigniter, I agree with `Wesley Murch`.

Comment: I think it is fixed in latest CI. CMIIW.

Comment: Have you got the solution mate? Cause I have found the same issues. In my case too the session is getting deleted when I am doing continuous ajax request. Please give me some idea to fix it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This hack fixed the problem for me.  It just cancels `sess_update` calls when the request is coming from an XHR request.

Define this in your `system/application/config/constants.php`:

```
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
```

Then, create `system/application/libraries/My_Session.php` with the following:

```
class MY_Session extends CI_Session {
    public function __construct($params = array())
    {
            parent::CI_Session($params);
    }

    public function sess_update()
    {
            if ( IS_AJAX )
            {
                    parent::sess_update();
            }
    }
}
```

Hack based on [this thread](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/172415/).  Only tested on CI 1.7.2, YMMV.

The problem was that I was fired ajax requests very quickly.  Periodically, a `sess_update` is triggered on one of them. And, sometimes, there would be a second ajax request at the same time.  That request would provide the recently expired session key, and code igniter would delete the session.

This fix works by only allowing session updates on non-ajax requests.  It's a kluge, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Change `sess_expire_on_close` in your session config file. Not quite sure why it helps... probably a bug in CI.